# How to aggregate a data frame column into a new column of lists with count?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame in scala like :

```
URL       Browser
A         Chrome
B         Chrome 
C         Firefox
A         Chrome
A         Firefox
A         Opera
A         Chrome
B         Chrome
B         Firefox
C         Tor
```

The URL column has a wide range of data, but the Browser column has a limited set.
I want to aggregate on the URL column and get the top counts for each browser in a list in descending order, like :

```
URL      FrequentlyUsedBrowser 
A        [(Chrome,3),(Firefox,1),(Opera,1)]
B        [(Chrome,2),(Firefox,1)]
C        [(Chrome,1),(Tor,1)]
```

I have been writing SQL for it to use window partition to get the count as one entry for each browser, but not been able to get it into a list.

This is for a google data proc cluster running Spark 2.4 with Scala 2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `collect_list` and sort by `sort_array`.

```
  df.withColumn("num", lit(1))
    .groupBy('url, 'browser)
    .agg(sum('num).as("num"))
    .select('url, format_string("(%s)",concat_ws(",", 'browser, 'num)).as("dst"))
    .groupBy('url)
    .agg(sort_array(collect_list('dst))).toDF("URL","FrequentlyUsedBrowser")
    .orderBy('url)
    .show(false)

+---+-------+
|url|browser|
+---+-------+
|  A| Chrome|
|  B| Chrome|
|  C|Firefox|
|  A| Chrome|
|  A|Firefox|
|  A|  Opera|
|  A| Chrome|
|  B| Chrome|
|  B|Firefox|
|  C|    Tor|
+---+-------+

+---+------------------------------------+
|URL|FrequentlyUsedBrowser               |
+---+------------------------------------+
|A  |[(Chrome,3), (Firefox,1), (Opera,1)]|
|B  |[(Chrome,2), (Firefox,1)]           |
|C  |[(Firefox,1), (Tor,1)]              |
+---+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: but this will sort alphabetical... not sort counts

Answer (score 0):

I made a modification to @chlebek's answer, adding an order by so it works perfectly for me now. The list is also sorted now. Thanks !!

```
df.withColumn("num", lit(1))
 .groupBy('url, 'browser)
 .agg(sum('num)
 .as("num"))
 .orderBy('num.desc)
 .select('url, format_string("(%s)",concat_ws(",", 'browser, 'num))
 .as("dst"))
 .groupBy('url)
 .agg(collect_list('dst))
 .toDF("URL","FrequentlyUsedBrowser")
 .orderBy('url).show(false)
```